# Installing FreeBSD in VirtualBox aborts unexpectedly

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, virtualbox

I have tried installing `FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-i386-dvd1.iso` into VirtualBox 3 times already today (each time starting from a fresh creation of a VM) and right when I'm about to Exit (Apply configuration and exit installer) the Final Configuration stage, I get this Abort error:

[image: FreeBSD Installer - Abort]

So then I either have to Restart or Exit...which is obviously not my end goal. I want to give FreeBSD a test drive in VirtualBox so I really want it to get installed. Hopefully someone can help.

Possibly relevant details:

- Host OS: 64-bit Arch Linux (Antergos)
- VirtualBox 4.3.14
- MD5 of ISO used checks out

**Update 1**

Opened another shell and checked `/tmp/bsdinstall_log`. Here are the last lines:

[image: bsdinstall_log]

I assume `umount` failed?

**Update 2**

As suggested in the comments, I disabled `Enable VT-x/AMD-V` and it aborts after I set the `root` password.

[image: bsdinstall_disable_vt-x_amd-v]

*The Abort dialog follows this screen*

Comment: It says installation step has been aborted, which means you tried to skip a step. Did you skip anything?

Comment: @toxemicsquire No. I followed the installation guide from the FreeBSD handbook. That's why it's baffling why I get an error saying I skipped a step.

Comment: @somethingSomething See update 2 in my question.

Comment: Have you read [errata](http://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.0R/errata.html#open-issues) and tried to set `set vfs.unmapped_buf_allowed=0` before boot, as advised?

Comment: Try going to the virtual machine's settings and enable PAE/NX. I was able to put together a install without problems and without using the command given in the errata.

Comment: @julp I didn't read the errata (facepalm). Can you make your comment an answer so I can choose it as such?

@Renan Tried setting the `PAE/NX` but still to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### "Unstable" FreeBSD 10/i386 on VirtualBox, Xen, KVM

#### For FreeBSD installation

On FreeBSD boot menu, when booting from installation media, choose: `3. Escape to loader prompt` to enter the following commands:

1. `set vfs.unmapped_buf_allowed=0` (enter)
2. `boot` (enter)

Then proceed to FreeBSD installation as usual.

#### To run your new FreeBSD system

Two solutions:

- before leaving FreeBSD installation, at the end, when it asks for opening a shell (which is chrooted on / of your new system), answer yes, modify /boot/loader.conf (`echo 'vfs.unmapped_buf_allowed=0' >> /boot/loader.conf`) then `exit` when you have done to reboot on it
- or, the first time you boot it, repeat the steps you have done for installation then add this line to your loader.conf (`echo 'vfs.unmapped_buf_allowed=0' >> /boot/loader.conf`)

Source : [FreeBSD 10.0 errata](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.0R/errata.html#open-issues)

Answer (score 0):

this was happening to me i came googling for it.

I fixed it by just increasing the vm ram in virtualbox from 128MB to 384MB, by default virtaulbox gave it 128 MB as soon as i selected freeBSD, but it recommends 768 MB for a similar net install version of debian. i dont think debian non-gui needs ~7 times more ram then freeBSD non-gui :)